# not valid map path in publish asp.net MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have problem in my webapp named "TezBuy" on release mode.
when i run the project , mappath is : D:\My Applications\TezBuy\EShop
but when publishing on localhost , the mappath is :C:\inetpub\wwwroot

how can i solve it? 
pls help me

Comment: It is not a problem. After publishing, the published website goes under IIS inetpub\wwwroot . Its the directory where all the hosted applications reside. BTW what is your problem ;)

Comment: tnx for your responce.

Comment: i cant't access to my folders and images to show and save

Comment: But that must be mapped as per your directory. Please re-configure and re-publish. What you need to take care is `/` will take you to the root, which after publishing will break. Use `ResolveClientUrl("~/Some/Url/");` , for mapping the files .

Comment: can u explain me more?

Comment: by the way tnx so much